# how to Bind the EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN in wxPyton for TaskBarIcon class

Tags: python, wxpython, python-3.6

I am new to Python and using `wxPython` to build a tool which can be minimize to system tray icon and can be restored when left clicked.
I have following code in Python 3. While searching online I found that I can bind the key like following snippet:

`self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnTaskBarLeftClick)`

However this is causing error saying that `wx doesn't have this attribute`.

I want to restore the main window when the task bar icon is left clicked, while right click creates a pop-up menu.

```
import wx
import wx.adv


class SysTrayMenu(wx.adv.TaskBarIcon):
    def __init__(self, frame, icon=None, menu=None):
       wx.adv.TaskBarIcon.__init__(self)
       self.frame = frame
       self.menu = menu
       self.icon = icon
       app_icon = wx.Icon()
       app_icon.CopyFromBitmap(wx.Bitmap(self.icon, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
       self.SetIcon(app_icon)

       self.Bind(wx.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnTaskBarLeftClick)

   def OnTaskBarLeftClick(self, evt):
       self.frame.Show()
       self.frame.Recover()

   def CreatePopupMenu(self):
       new_menu = wx.Menu()
       return self.menu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing it wrong. To make the menu pop-up I had to bind it with wx.EVT_MENU.

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.click_me, id=self.m_cb.GetId())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `TaskBarIcon` class is in the `wx.adv` module then the coresponding event binders and event type IDs are also in `wx.adv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below instead. Pls. note the event should be wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, not wx.adv.wxEVT_TASKBAR_BALLOON_CLICK. I was mislead by the prompts of pycharm before.

self.Bind(wx.adv.EVT_TASKBAR_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_down)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.